# Convert HTML table to an image

Tags: php, html, fpdf

i'm facing a problem.

I have to "copy" an html table into a pdf using fpdf.

Is it possible to convert an HTML table to an image (URL link) ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Most things are possible, as long as you do the required research and actually try something.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the table using fpdf but it might be easier to copy it as an image thanks to an url link

Comment: Presumably we're talking server-side here and you're not just asking for a browser plugin that can convert HTML to PDF client-side on the fly?

Comment: [html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf)

Comment: [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) has very similar syntax to FPDF and includes a `writeHTML()` function which would output your table.

Comment: CD001 No I have to create a button generating my pdf page

Answer (score 0):

I find `wkhtmltopdf` much better.

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

Then download the PHP class:

```
https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf
```

Using it is really easy:

```
    <?php

    use mikehaert\wkhtmlto\Pdf;

    $pdf = new Pdf(array('tmpDir' => '/optional/tmp/folder/here'));
    $pdf->addPage('http://google.com');

    // Save the PDF
    // $pdf->saveAs('/tmp/new.pdf');

    // ... or send to client for inline display
    if (!$pdf->send()) {echo $pdf->getError();}

    // ... or send to client as file download
    // $pdf->send('test.pdf');
```

You may get an error saying it cannot connect to the X server. If you get this, you probably don’t have X installed! I didn’t, it’s a web server, not a desktop machine!

In the event that you have no X server, go into the Command.php class, you will see the following option:

```
/**
 * @var bool whether to enable the built in Xvfb support (uses xvfb-run)
 */
public $enableXvfb = false;
```

Change this to true, and try again. This time it should work!

If it still doesn’t, then possibly you also need to install xvfb, let me know and i can send instructions for that too if required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try that.

Comment: let me know how you get on!

Answer (score -1):

You can keep that html table inside a div. when clicking on a button (button clicked to generate pdf), take a screenshot for that div tag, you can save that screenshot into a temporary folder and can copy to pdf file on the fly.

Comment: How would you take the screenshot?

Comment: Please follow the below link http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/html2canvas-take-screenshot-of-web-page-and-save-it-to-server-javascript-and-php/